# UnicodeDecodeError in smart_select in JSON QuerySet

Tags: django, json, python-unicode

I'm using [Smart Select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) to join two models using a another one. But when `smart_select` builds the filter, I get an error 500. When put the server in Debug mode I can see the Exception Type

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/cmi/cmi/smart_selects/views.py" in filterchain
  21.     results.sort(cmp=locale.strcoll, key=lambda x: unicode_sorter(unicode(x)))
File "/opt/cmi/cmi/smart_selects/views.py" in <lambda>
  21.     results.sort(cmp=locale.strcoll, key=lambda x: unicode_sorter(unicode(x)))

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /chaining/filter/rechazos/Causa/conjunto/1/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The desired output is like this:

```
[{"display": "A - DOC sin huella(s) en el \u00e1rea de solicitud", "value": 1}, {"display": "B1 - DOC sin firma en el \u00e1rea de solicitud", "value": 2}, {"display": "M1 - Documento roto y/o manchado", "value": 7}, {"display": "O - Faltante f\u00edsico detectado en el paquete DOC", "value": 8}, {"display": "O2 - Faltante f\u00edsico detectado en el paquete DOC", "value": 5}
```

I my windows 8, with the same code and same data, I'm unable to reproduce this error.

Relevants parts of the app can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/jstoledano/6083353

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- Python: 2.7.3
- MySQL:  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31

  - Character Set: UTF-8
  - Collation: utf8_bin

Comment: So where the error is appearing? And it'll be good to see some actual code.

Comment: Using smart_select I'm pretend to prefill a select control with a filtered QuerySet, but the control is empty. Looking in the Google Chrome's Console I can see the error 500.

Comment: Can you show us the problematic code as well as the operating system and python version that are giving you trouble?